# foreach for php merging and adding the total amount in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

So guys I have a php code here:

```
    <?php foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
    <?php $totamount = ($post->price) * ($post->qty); ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price<th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="name"><?php echo $post->name; ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="qty"><?php echo $post->qty; ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="price"><?php echo $post->price; ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="totamount"><?php echo $totamount; ?></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="client"><?php echo $post->firstname; ?> <?php echo $post->lastname; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

If the client reserves one product it is good, but when the client adds new product, the receipt would look like this:

```
    Item Name    Quantity    Price   Total
     gown           2        7.50     15

    clients name

    Item Name    Quantity    Price   Total
    bridal          1        5.00      5

    clients name
```

Suddenly this became a loop, you can see that the `<th>` is looping and also the client name, I want it to be like this:

```
    Item Name    Quantity    Price   Total
     gown           2        7.50     15
    bridal          1        5.00      5

                       TOTAL AMOUNT:  20

    clients name
```

And also, how can I get the TOTAL AMOUNT without using SQL because Total is not in the database! How will I do everything right?

Comment: If you don't want headings and client's name repeated, just remove them from the loop. To total, just add all of the values in another variable as you move through the loop... `$total += $post->price;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in the loop only the `<tr>` with the product info:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price<th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
        <?php $totamount = ($post->price) * ($post->qty); 
        $orderTotal += $totamount;
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="name"><?php echo $post->name; ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="qty"><?php echo $post->qty; ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="price"><?php echo $post->price; ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="totamount"><?php echo $totamount; ?></div></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
<div class="total"><?=$orderTotal?></div>
<div class="client"><?php echo $post->firstname; ?> <?php echo $post->lastname; ?></div>
```

Comment: tried it but there is an error it says Undefined variable $orderTotal

Comment: try to initialise it outside the for $orderTotal = 0;